# Gravity Form Stripe Payments not submitting

Tags: wordpress, forms, stripe-payments, gravity

We have had some issues with Gravity Form Stripe add-on. Submissions are not consistently working. The error occurs for me mostly on iPhone Safari and Firefox on Mac and have caused issues for my client also. However have had them work previously. The form doesn't submit, nor any payment goes through to Stripe, the form stays loading.

Link to the payment form: https://rachelsmusiccentre.com/make-a-payment/

Error in the console:

Feature Policy: Skipping unsupported feature name “payment”.

Console errors
[image: Console errors]

the form with submission left loading
[image: the form with submission left loading]

Let me know if there's anything I can help clarify further, and appreciate your help!